# Find random 10 people Wikidata

Tags: wikidata, sparql

Using Sparql I can find person on Wikdata by his name:

```
SELECT distinct (SAMPLE(?image)as ?image) ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
                (SAMPLE(?DR) as ?DR)(SAMPLE(?RIP) as ?RIP)(SAMPLE(?article) as ?article)
                WHERE {?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5. ?item ?label 'Putin' @en. OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P569 ?DR .}
                ?article schema:about ?item . ?article schema:inLanguage 'en'. ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
                OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P570 ?RIP .}
                OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P18 ?image .}
                SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'en'. }}
                GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
```

[See this on Wikidat Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fimage%29as%20%3Fimage%29%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FDR%29%20as%20%3FDR%29%28SAMPLE%28%3FRIP%29%20as%20%3FRIP%29%28SAMPLE%28%3Farticle%29%20as%20%3Farticle%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%27Putin%27%20%40en.%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FDR%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%27en%27.%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP570%20%3FRIP%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%27en%27.%20%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription)

Or if you know his ID:

```
SELECT distinct (SAMPLE(?image)as ?image)  ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
            (SAMPLE(?DR) as ?DR)(SAMPLE(?RIP) as ?RIP)(SAMPLE(?article) as ?article)
            WHERE{ ?article  schema:about ?item ; schema:inLanguage  'en' ; schema:isPartOf    <https://en.wikipedia.org/>
            FILTER ( ?item = <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q303> )
            OPTIONAL { ?item  wdt:P569  ?DR }
            OPTIONAL { ?item  wdt:P570  ?RIP }
            OPTIONAL { ?item  wdt:P18  ?image }
            SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language  'en'}}
            GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
```

[This query on Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fimage%29as%20%3Fimage%29%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FDR%29%20as%20%3FDR%29%28SAMPLE%28%3FRIP%29%20as%20%3FRIP%29%28SAMPLE%28%3Farticle%29%20as%20%3Farticle%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%7B%20%3Farticle%20%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20%3B%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%20%27en%27%20%3B%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%20%20%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%3Fitem%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ303%3E%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20%20wdt%3AP569%20%20%3FDR%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20%20wdt%3AP570%20%20%3FRIP%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20%20wdt%3AP18%20%20%3Fimage%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%20%27en%27%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription)

But can't figure out how to get several random persons. If I remove search criteria and add limit 10, I get timeout, probably because it query all people even I just want 5 or 10.

Any idea how I can get 10 random people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code gives different 10s of people in different runs (Random) but it gives new results only when running incognito or private tab (May be because of caching)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P31 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q5.
    }
    LIMIT 10
  }
}ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100
```

[image: Screenshot of query results]